# Shortest path from osmar object to igraph in R. Trying to replicate an osmar documentation example

Tags: r, openstreetmap, igraph, shortest-path, osmar

i am trying to get started with openstreetmap in R and try to replicate the example given in osmar package documentation.

I get a bit data for munich.

```
src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")

muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 1000, 1000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
```

I get a subset of all highways in munich

```
    hways_muc <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
hways <- find(hways_muc, way(tags(k == "name")))
hways <- find_down(muc, way(hways))
hways_muc <- subset(muc, ids = hways)
```

Then I find a node with "Tor" in a name of it and a nearest highway:

```
  hway_start_node <- local({
  id<-find(muc, node(tags(v %agrep% "tor")))[1]
  find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway"))) })

  hway_start <- subset(muc, node(hway_start_node))
```

Then I pick some random point and a nearest highway to it:

```
hway_end_node <- local({
  id <- find(muc, node(attrs(lon > 11.58 & lat > 47.150)))[1]
  find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway"))) })
```

Now I convert osmar object to igraph and get stuck

```
    gr_muc <- as_igraph(hways_muc)
route <- get.shortest.paths(gr_muc, from = as.character(hway_start_node), to =    as.character(hway_end_node))[[1]]
```

I get this error:

```
Fehler in as.igraph.vs(graph, from) : Invalid vertex names
```

How do i dress the nodes in igraph correctly? 
From what I understand I use the node ids but it seems I can not find or address them in igraph.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors:
1. GPS coordinate chosen is not reachable.
2. GPS coordinate chosen can only be reached if you ignore one directional roads

1.Change this line :

```
id<-find(muc, node(tags(v %agrep% "tor")))[1]
```

to

```
id<-find(muc, node(tags(v %agrep% "Sendlinger Tor")))[1]
```

Change this line:

```
id <- find(muc, node(attrs(lon > 11.58 & lat > 47.150)))[1]
```

to

```
  id <- find(muc, node(attrs(lon > 11.58 & lat > 48.150)))[1]
```

also change the graph to be undirected.

```
gr_muc<-as.undirected(gr_muc)

route <- get.shortest.paths(gr_muc, from = as.character(hway_start_node), to =    as.character(hway_end_node))[[1]]
```

further down in the exmple the Author makes a small mistake so be aware to use this line of code to select one route from a list:

```
route=route[[1]]
```